# How to log CORS origin fails with Quarkus

Tags: java, cors, quarkus, quarkus-reactive

I currently have an app that has CORS properly configured. https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#cors-filter

It is currently responding 403 for a small amount of requests. However, I'm unable to identify the origin of those requests. Is there a way to log the origin only when CORS validation fails (and not always)?

Quarkus 2.16.10

Comment: We've opened a simple PR to log them: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/35959, note in some cases it is already logged, example: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/vertx-http/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/vertx/http/runtime/cors/CORSFilter.java#L257, but it will be more complete now

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using 2.16.10, and I understand that I will need to update to v3 to get the PR changes.
To enable the current logs I should do something like `quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.cors.CORSFilter".level=DEBUG`, right?

Comment: I've added a backport to 2.16 label as well